# Remove footer's blocks in cms page using layout update

Tags: blocks, layout-update

I created a cms page, but I don't want footer to display on this page, I added below line at layout update,

```
<reference name="footer">
    <remove name="footer_links" />
</reference>
```

I am using magento 1.9 rwd theme to test.

But the footer still exists, I remember I had done similar thing in the past, but I forgot how to do it twice again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout XML should be like this.

```
<cms_page>
    <reference name="footer">
           <remove name="footer_links" />
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

This will remove blocks from your cms page.

Comment: still can't remove

Comment: Have you cleared chache ?

Comment: done, after cleared the cache!

Answer (score 0):

this will remove the footer link block from footer

```
 <cms_page>
    <remove name="footer_links"/>
 </cms_page>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to completely rid-off the footer section, then use this :

```
 <remove name="footer />
```

Or if you need to keep footer section but need to removes footer links.

```
<reference name="footer">
    <remove name="footer_links" />
    <remove name="footer_links2" />
</reference>
```

But the very important step that you are missing here is **FLUSH YOUR CACHE**. Do that if you didnt do that yet and refresh the page again.

---

<sup>Here I assume you are going to add layout updates in the layout udpate section in admin section</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default rwd theme, the footer links are divided into different block.

To check them, open `page.xml` and `cms.xml` from `rwd/default/layout`. There you will find two block `footer_links`, `footer_links2`

Now in `cms.xm`l you will find the block `cms_footer_links`. You can remove them as per your requirements.

To remove it from particular CMS page, follow below steps

1) Goto `CMS >> Pages >> CMS PAGE YOU OF YOUR CHOICE`

2) Open the design tab and insert below code

```
<remove name="footer_links" />
<remove name="footer_links2" />
<remove name="cms_footer_links" />
```

You can remove other elements from the CMS page using the similar technique, you will just have to find the name of the blocks to remove them.